# Global libraries with system.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got following set up in my index.html:

```
...
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>

<script src="components/traceur/traceur.js"></script>
<script src="components/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js"></script>
<script src="components/system.js/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
    System.baseURL = '/';
</script>

<script type="module">
    // Example
    import angular from 'angular';

    angular.module('myApp', [...]);
</script>
```

I'd like to load angular.js (and some other common libs) globally via script tag. But when I'm trying to use it in modules (in my case, es6-modules) system.js tries to load it via URL `http://mysite/angular.js`. It just doesn't see that I've already included it as global lib. I spent several hours figuring out how can I handle this, read system.js wiki on Github, but I'm still stuck with this.

Can anybody show how to configure system.js to work with global libs?

Comment: that goes against the whole point of using a module loader like System. If you really want to do this anyway, see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/systemjs/0_tuZW5s-JY

Comment: What about big ones where you want to include them outside your SystemJS build: a) for build performance reasons, b) because other things rely on them being global. For example I want to use Three.js and also the Three.js 'extra' ColladaLoader which attaches itself to the global THREE object... Browserify-shim, for example, recommends doing that by including them with separate script tags.

Comment: The SystemJS docs recommend adapter modules for globals via separate script includes (https://github.com/systemjs/builder#adapter-modules). However, this doesn't help if you're using a library that require()'s it via its npm name... :(

Answer (score 7):

```
System.registerDynamic('angular', [], false, function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = window.angular;
});
```

or

```
System.set('angular', System.newModule({
    "default": window.angular
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was missing! The SystemJS documentation wasn't very helpful